# how to apply design fallback only on one module? is that possible?

Tags: magento-enterprise, theme-fallback

so I am creating a custom grid template named grid.phtml(I will tell why i did not rename it) , here is the configuration :

[image]

when I did this:
[image]
It didn't pick up the scosche first, it again goes to the default/default I solved it, I added this code in my config.xml module:

```
 <stores>
    <admin>
        <design>
            <package>
                <name>default</name>
            </package>
            <theme>
                <default>scosche</default>
            </theme>
        </design>
    </admin>
</stores>
```

everything now works fine, it will first go search in scosche folder and grab grid.phtml and if it is not there it will read from the default one

the thing is grid.phtml in all other modules(like manage products grid) will now read from scosche folder, though I just wanted to specifically read from here for this specific module, to solve, I can go to my module Grid.php and rename the grid and do this:

```
$this->setTemplate('widget/customgrid.phtml');
```

and then have this:
[image]

so other modules go search in scosche and they see grid.phtml is not there and so go to default folder, and for only this one it is customgrid.phtml

I am changing the whole concept through all the design fallback I just wanted to have it **specifically** for **one module**. I am working on a test stage, what if by adding this fallback, the scosche had some files and read them?! in some other places?! so seems my solution is not that effective at least I think it is not.

also I do not want to change the design tab of configuration at all, I want to just customize my module.

I am curious if there is a way that I can have design fall back only on my module not in the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the `package/theme` settings in your first picture don't apply to the `adminhtml` theme.

Second, create your `grid.phtml` in the `default/default` package/theme.  For example, if your module name is `Company_Scosche` I would put the template in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/company/scosche/widget/grid.phtml`

Then in your admin grid block, set this new template

```
class Company_Scosche_Block_Adminhtml_Scosche_Grid
     extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    /**
     * Initialize grid
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('company/scosche/widget/grid.phtml');
        // ....
    }
    // ....
}
```

This should apply your custom template to this one block, without having to change the whole theme.

Comment: but I thought that I shouldn't touch the default folder and put it there, because default is like base folder we do want to keep magento original files there is it really a good practice?

Comment: You shouldn't modify existing files in the `default` folder (that's editing core), but you can add new ones.